# Clone and append previous tr row to current table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having a table with 3 rows, with inputs where you can fill values in.

Now I have a link in the last tr, that says "+ More".

The "+ More" link, should if worked as expected, clone the above tr and append it above the link.

This is how far I am:

http://jsfiddle.net/9s8LH/2/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.appendRow').bind('click', function(){
        var $table = $(this).closest('table');

        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var $trAbove = $(this).prev('tr');

        $table.append($tr.clone());

    });
});
```

I tried to use `prev('tr')` to grab the TR element before the one I am inside, but it does not really work.

The second issue is that it appends under the +More TR, and not above it.

How can this be done?

Comment: *"... but it does not really work."* Doesn't work ***how***?

Comment: Put the relevant markup in the question as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that `$(this).prev('tr')` doesn't work is that your `appendRow` class is on the *link*, not the row. There is no `tr` immediately prior to the *link*, `prev` looks at the previous sibling element (sibling = within the same parent) to see if it matches the selector. It doesn't scan, and it doesn't go up the hierarchy.

You're pretty close though, see comments: [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9s8LH/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.appendRow').bind('click', function(){
        // First get the current row
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');

        // Now the one above it
        var $trAbove = $tr.prev('tr');

        // Now insert the clone
        $trAbove.clone().insertBefore($tr);
    });
});
```

Note the use of [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore), which will insert the clone before the current row.

Comment: Thank you for your time, explained it perfectly for me. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on) for dynamically added elements and you **HTML** should be like,

**HTML**

```
<table class="extraBookingBox">
    <tr><td>Fees</td><td>Amount</td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 40px;" name="cancelfee_price[]" />€</td>
        <td><input type="text" style="width: 40px;" name="cancelfee_price[]" />€</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><a href="#" class="appendRow">+ More</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.appendRow', function(){        
        var $tr = $('table tr:nth-child(2)').clone(); 
        console.log($tr);
        $tr.insertBefore($('.appendRow').closest('tr'));        
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6pp7w/)

Comment: The `appendRow` element isn't dynamically added, and `document` seems surprisingly far away from the element to be hooking this for delegation (wouldn't the table have been a better choice?).

Comment: Check the OP demo you can see the `add more` is added dynamically only.